# Async servlet in embedded jetty seems to write to wrong response at high load

Tags: java, asynchronous, jetty, servlet-3.0

The code given below works fine when I send manual requests. If I generate requests with siege (`siege -c 500 -r 100 'http://localhost:8080/?name=Chandru&age=560'`), I start seeing these messages in jetty's log:

```
2013-01-02 00:06:55.761:WARN:oejh.HttpGenerator:Ignoring extra content {name: "
2013-01-02 00:07:56.393:WARN:oejh.HttpGenerator:Ignoring extra content Chandru
2013-01-02 00:07:56.393:WARN:oejh.HttpGenerator:Ignoring extra content ", age: 
2013-01-02 00:07:56.393:WARN:oejh.HttpGenerator:Ignoring extra content 560
2013-01-02 00:07:56.393:WARN:oejh.HttpGenerator:Ignoring extra content }
```

I'm using Jetty 8.1.8.v20121106 on Java 1.7.0_10.What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Server server = new Server(8080);
        final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");
        final ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(new RequestHandler(new Responder()));
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        context.addServlet(servlet, "/");
        server.start();
    }
}

class RequestHandler extends HttpServlet {

    private final Responder responder;

    public RosterHandler(Responder responder) {
        this.responder = responder;
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        responder.process(request.startAsync());
    }
}

class Responder {

    private final ExecutorService pool;

    public Responder() {
        this.pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    }

    public void process(final AsyncContext ctx) {
        pool.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                final String name = ctx.getRequest().getParameter("name");
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(ctx.getRequest().getParameter("age"));

                ctx.getResponse().setContentType("application/json");
                try (final PrintWriter w = ctx.getResponse().getWriter()) {
                    w.printf("{name: \"%s\", age: %d}", name, age);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it normal to use instance variables in servlets now? It never used to be, in fact, it was almost always a bug in disguise. I don't know if recent JEE allows that to work-find that out first.

Comment: Having an instance variable in servlet is a problem because it can be accessed by multiple request threads in parallel. Since Responder is thread-safe, it's safe to have it as an instance variable.

Here is an example where this is done from java.net. http://weblogs.java.net/blog/meeraj/archive/2005/12/resource_inject.html

Comment: ewe, deleted response after re-reading, it only applied to servlet path and path info, not what your dealing with.  looking again does it change when you call complete() on the context?  with that example if it doesn't work try posting a bug on bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty and we'll take a look

Comment: @jessemcconnell ctx.complete() worked. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call context.complete() to signal that your work is done and the async connection can be considered finished.